# How to share SESSION between LARAVEL user and GUZZLE

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am using Guzzle from my Laravel application to CURL into another Laravel application.
**The user database is shared between these apps and both use the same session table In a common database.**

I want to pass the session from the first Laravel app (which users have access directly) to the nested Laravel apps (which users have access through guzzle request).

the first laravel app is a front that acts as a subdirectory or somehow similar to a reverse proxy, getting the user request and delivering the requested page via a making guzzle request and returning the response.

[I have followed the instructions of this blog](https://medium.com/@zsolt.gyure96/how-to-share-sessions-between-two-laravel-applications-4b9d061fa599) but due to the difference of user-agent and etc in the request of guzzle and user, it does not work.

**is there any way to make the guzzle use an existing session from another laravel app and user agent?**